# Match as close to n characters as possible, given that the last character is a space or end/beginning of row

Tags: regex

I want to extract some 50 characters to the left and right of a certain word, but to make sure the outermost characters are not split the last character has to be either space, beginning of row or end of row. I tried something like this without success:

```
^.*(\s{0,50}(word)\s{0,50}).*$
```

This matches "word", but ends abruptly just before and after.

For example, using "... test test word test test ...", it matches " word ".

Comment: Could you please add some sample text and sample results.

Comment: Here's a test sample: http://regexr.com?37ur1

Answer (score 2, accepted):

By using `\s{0,50}` you are effectively trying to match 0-50 spaces. You might want to change `\s` to either the characters you want (e.g `[a-zA-Z\s.]` or `.` to match all).

My suggestion is the following:

```
((\b.{0,50})?(word)(.{0,50}\b)?)
```

Note that I had to create two new groups and make them optional, so that the boundary would be matched. You might also want to add `\b` inside the groups to separate your `word` from the rest, like so:

```
((\b.{0,50}\b)?(word)(\b.{0,50}\b)?)
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use this regex to extract upto 50 characters to the left and right of a certain word:

```
(.{0,50}\bword\b.{0,50})
```

#### Online Demo: http://regex101.com/r/uV8pL6

**Explanation:**

```
1st Capturing group (.{0,50}\bword\b.{0,50})
.{0,50} matches any character (except newline)
Quantifier: Between 0 and 50 #, as many times as possible, giving back as needed [greedy]
\b assert position at a word boundary (^\w|\w$|\W\w|\w\W)
word matches the characters word literally (case sensitive)
\b assert position at a word boundary (^\w|\w$|\W\w|\w\W)
.{0,50} matches any character (except newline)
Quantifier: Between 0 and 50 #, as many times as possible, giving back as needed [greedy]
```